# Create statistical chart by week and month android

Tags: android

I want to create statistical chart by week and month,same as the picture below, Which library should I use? thank you
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information , what you tried that also

Comment: use MPChart library

Answer (score 1):

You can do this graph easily with native android components, but if you are looking for a library, then have a look at MPAndroidChart https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart